# Design - prevent multiple nesting in function

Tags: design-patterns, groovy

I have a function written in Groovy which needs to save a record and also return response from the server.
Function is working fine, but I am not happy with the design because I have a problem with multiple nesting.

**This is the function:**

```
Map scanAccessRecord(GrailsParameterMap params){

    Map response
    Date currentTime = new Date()
    String readerEthernetAddress = params.readerMac
    Reader reader = Reader.findByDeletedAndEthernetAddress(false, readerEthernetAddress)
    Boolean isAccessIn = (params.isAccessIn == "True")

    if(reader)
    {
        UserSettings userSettings = UserSettings.findByRfidCode(params.rfid.toString())

        if(userSettings)
        {
            if(userSettings.user.company.id == reader.companyId)
            {
                AccessRecord accessRecord = new AccessRecord(reader:reader, userId:userSettings.userId, specificDate:currentTime, isAccessIn: isAccessIn)

                if(accessRecord.save(flush: true))
                {
                    response = [
                            status: '00',
                            message: 'OK',
                            recordId: accessRecord.id,
                    ]
                }
                else
                {
                    response = [
                            status: '60',
                            message: 'error'
                    ]
                }
            }
            else
            {
                response = [status: '40', message: 'USER AND READER ARE NOT FROM SAME COMPANY']
            }
        }
        else
        {
            response = [status: '10', message: 'UNKNOWN USER']
        }
    }
    else
    {
        response = [status: '50', message: 'READER NOT FOUND']
    }

    return response
}
```

What can I do to make this function "cleaner"?

Comment: Not familiar with groovy. Is `if(reader)` is a null check?

Comment: Yes, it is checking whether there is a reader or not

Comment: In what case reader is null?

Comment: `Reader reader = Reader.findByDeletedAndEthernetAddress(false, readerEthernetAddress)`

Reader is NULL in the case there is no reader found in DB with `readerEthernetAddress`(mac address) given in params or if it is found but has a flag `deleted`.

Comment: Is AccessRecord your code or some framework? I Want to understand why `save` returns boolean.

Comment: `AccessRecord` is domainClass which I created, but `.save()` method is method which is automatically given to domainClasses in Grails framework.

About you question, here is an answer from official documentaion:

"The save method returns null if validation failed and the instance was not persisted, or the instance itself if successful. This lets you use "Groovy truth" (null is considered false) to write code like the following:"

Comment: Why `params.isAccessIn` is a string and not boolean?

Comment: Because request is sent from a Python(Python script is in a reader) and it was easiest to send a string value which I just needed to convert to Boolean in Groovy.

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, is too general to be useful here. Please [edit] to the site standard, which is for the title to simply state **the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Use optional instead of null. I wrote an [article](https://link.medium.com/2dU1PEeqk6) about avoiding nulls if you are interested.
- Use early returns to avoid nesting

  ```
  If !reader return [status: '50', message: 'READER NOT FOUND']

  If !userSettings return...
  Rest of the logic
  ```
- I prefer to avoid nulls,so I would choose to call save with `failOnError=true` and it will throw exception instead of returning null when save fails.
- I assume  you want any exception to return [ status: '60', message: 'error'], if you use `save` with `failOnError=true` then the error is handled in one place only.
- add validation for `params.isAccessIn`. If by mistake it is nor true or false, it is better to throw error than do something the client didn't intend to.
- Maybe you should be more flexible with `params.isAccessIn` and compare strings without case sensitivity.

Comment: Although I am not preferring using early returns in my code, I need to admin that they are very good solution in this case :)

Answer (score 3):

This is the kind of code I'm having a hard time with myself, so I played around and tried different approaches.

### `else` closer to `if` condition

The `if` blocks are far away from their corresponding `else` blocks. Once you reach the `else` block you have to go all the way up to lookup what the `if` condition was. So I would negate all the `if` conditions. That brings the `else` closer to the `if`.

```
Map scanAccessRecord(GrailsParameterMap params) {
    Date currentTime = new Date()
    String readerEthernetAddress = params.readerMac
    Reader reader = Reader.findByDeletedAndEthernetAddress(false, readerEthernetAddress)
    Boolean isAccessIn = (params.isAccessIn == "True")

    if (!reader) {
        [status: '50', message: 'READER NOT FOUND']
    } else {
        UserSettings userSettings = UserSettings.findByRfidCode(params.rfid.toString())
        if (!userSettings) {
            [status: '10', message: 'UNKNOWN USER']
        } else {
            if (userSettings.user.company.id != reader.companyId) {
                [status: '40', message: 'USER AND READER ARE NOT FROM SAME COMPANY']
            } else {
                AccessRecord accessRecord = new AccessRecord(reader: reader, userId: userSettings.userId, specificDate: currentTime, isAccessIn: isAccessIn)
                if (!accessRecord.save(flush: true)) {
                    [status: '60', message: 'error']
                } else {
                    response = [status: '00', message: 'OK', recordId: accessRecord.id]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe not beautiful, but I think there's nothing wrong with the code.

### Early Returns

```
Map scanAccessRecordNew(GrailsParameterMap params){
    Date currentTime = new Date()
    String readerEthernetAddress = params.readerMac
    Reader reader = Reader.findByDeletedAndEthernetAddress(false, readerEthernetAddress)
    Boolean isAccessIn = (params.isAccessIn == "True")

    if(!reader)
        return [status: '50', message: 'READER NOT FOUND']

    UserSettings userSettings = UserSettings.findByRfidCode(params.rfid.toString())

    if(!userSettings)
        return [status: '10', message: 'UNKNOWN USER']

    if(userSettings.user.company.id != reader.companyId)
        return [status: '40', message: 'USER AND READER ARE NOT FROM SAME COMPANY']

    AccessRecord accessRecord = new AccessRecord(reader:reader, userId:userSettings.userId, specificDate:currentTime, isAccessIn: isAccessIn)

    if(!accessRecord.save(flush: true))
        return  [status: '60', message: 'error']

    return [status: '00', message: 'OK', recordId: accessRecord.id]
}
```

Is this more readable? Maybe, but I don't like early returns so much either.

### Functional Style

Maybe functional programming is the solution. We could use something like `Either` in Scala. Java's built-in `Optional` is not well suited when you want to return the reason why something went wrong. Sadly, there is no `Either` in Standard Java. I have used [vavr.io](https://www.vavr.io/) some time ago:

```
Map scanAccessRecord(GrailsParameterMap params){
    Date currentTime = new Date()
    Boolean isAccessIn = (params.isAccessIn == "True")

    Either reader = findReader(params.readerMac)
    Either userSetting = findUserSetting(params.rfid.toString()).flatMap {
        u -> reader.flatMap { r -> verifyCompanyId(u, r) }
    }

    Either accessRecord = reader.flatMap { r ->
        userSetting.map { u ->
            new AccessRecord(reader:r, userId:u.userId, specificDate:currentTime, isAccessIn: isAccessIn)
        }
    }

    accessRecord.map { saveAccessRecord(it) }.getOrElseGet {it }
}


Either<Map, Reader> findReader(String readerEthernetAddress){
    Reader reader = Reader.findByDeletedAndEthernetAddress(false, readerEthernetAddress)
    reader ? Either.right(reader)
           : Either.left([status: '50', message: 'READER NOT FOUND'])
}

Either<Map, UserSettings> findUserSetting(String rfid){
    UserSettings userSettings = UserSettings.findByRfidCode(rfid)
    userSettings ? Either.right(userSettings)
                 : Either.left([status: '10', message: 'UNKNOWN USER'])
}

Either<Map, UserSettings> verifyCompanyId(UserSettings userSettings, Reader reader){
    userSettings.user.company.id == reader.companyId
        ? Either.right(userSettings)
        : Either.left([status: '40', message: 'USER AND READER ARE NOT FROM SAME COMPANY'])
}

Map saveAccessRecord(AccessRecord accessRecord){
    accessRecord.save(flush: true)
        ? [status: '00', message: 'OK', recordId: accessRecord.id]
        : [status: '60', message: 'error']
}
```

The code in the method `scanAccessRecord` is somewhat cleaner. But overall the code is longer. And nested `flatMap`s without syntactic sugar are not easy to read. Does that justify another 3rd party library in your system? Probably not.

### Just for Fun

Map-like types are often used for communication between webservices. The pattern:

- status is 0: OK
- status is not 0: Error

is very common. So why not use that for something similar to `Either`? In Groovy we can manipulate the `Map` class at runtime and add two little methods `map` and `merge` calling the method `loadMetaUtils()` below.

```
Map scanAccessRecord(GrailsParameterMap params){
    loadMetaUtils()
    Date currentTime = new Date()
    Boolean isAccessIn = (params.isAccessIn == "True")

    Map r = findReader(params.readerMac)
    Map u = findUserSetting(params.rfid.toString())
    u.merge(r).map { verifyCompanyId(userSettings, reader) }
        .map { saveAccessRecord(new AccessRecord(reader:reader, userId:userSettings.userId, specificDate:currentTime, isAccessIn: isAccessIn))}
}


Map findReader(String readerEthernetAddress){
    Reader reader = Reader.findByDeletedAndEthernetAddress(false, readerEthernetAddress)
    reader ? [status: '00', reader: reader]
           : [status: '50', message: 'READER NOT FOUND']
}

Map findUserSetting(String rfid){
    UserSettings userSettings = UserSettings.findByRfidCode(rfid)
    userSettings ? [status: '00', userSettings: userSettings]
                 : [status: '10', message: 'UNKNOWN USER']
}

Map verifyCompanyId(UserSettings userSettings, Reader reader){
    userSettings.user.company.id == reader.companyId
            ? [status: '00', userSettings: userSettings, reader: reader]
            : [status: '40', message: 'USER AND READER ARE NOT FROM SAME COMPANY']
}

Map saveAccessRecord(AccessRecord accessRecord){
    accessRecord.save(flush: true)
        ? [status: '00', message: 'OK', recordId: accessRecord.id]
        : [status: '60', message: 'error']
}

void loadMetaUtils() {
    Map.metaClass.map << { Closure f ->
        if(delegate.status != '00') return delegate
        f.setDelegate(delegate)
        f.setResolveStrategy(Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST)
        f()
    }

    Map.metaClass.merge << { Map other ->
        if(delegate.status != '00') return delegate
        if(other.status != '00') return other
        delegate + other
    }
}
```

You lose all the type saftey, but if you are already dealing with Maps - maybe that's fine. Maybe that's a good way to get your colleagues to like functional programming...

I believe it very much depends on the style used in the code base and the complexity of the method, but in this particular case I would probably go with the first version.